# Java encoding filename Content-Disposition

Tags: java, firefox, gwt, encoding, content-disposition

I have GWT app from where I can download some files. And I've got a problem with encoding.

Here is some code:

```
String n = "Żółw testuje ąśżźć !#$%~ du";
String tmp = new String();
for(int i = 0; i < n.length(); i++) {
    String t = Character.toString(n.charAt(i));
    if(" =-_]}[{)(&^%$#@!~`,".contains(t))
        tmp +=t;
    else
        tmp += URLEncoder.encode(t, "UTF-8");
}

response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + tmp +"\"");
System.out.println(tmp);
```

In Chrome and IE the filename is "Żółw testuje ąśżźć !#$%~ du" but in Firefox is "%C5%BB%C3%B3%C5%82w testuje %C4%85%C5%9B%C5%BC%C5%BA%C4%87 !#$%~ du". I already tested with Windows-1252, ISO-8859-1, Cp852 and with "attachment; filename*=utf-8''" but no good.

Any suggestions?

Comment: WHy the downvote? Seems like a perfectly legitimate question to me

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http), but the post is 3 years old, I don't know how the situation has evolved since then

Comment: Thx fge, sporaks answer was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

See the relevant spec -- http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc6266.html -- and the test cases at http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/.